# YTPlayerView (youTube) Payer is not playing video in iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, sdk

I'am trying to play YouTube video in `UITableViewCell`, but it's not working in iOS 11. Below is the code.

---

```
CGRect videoFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.videoPlayerView.bounds.size.width, 211);
YTPlayerView *player = [[YTPlayerView alloc]initWithFrame:videoFrame];
NSString *videoId = [[BARUtility shared] getYoutubeVideoId:content.featuredVideoUrl];
NSDictionary *playerVars = @{@"controls" : @"0",
                             @"playsinline" : @"0",
                             @"rel" : @"0"};
if (videoId.length > 0) {
     [player loadWithVideoId:videoId playerVars:playerVars];
     [cell.videoPlayerView addSubview:player];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to add player to the container and then start the video?